# How to add a white space after each series of x terms of an array ? Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Imagine I have an array:

```
x = np.array(['1', '3', '5', '4', '8', '2'])
```

The goal is to add a whitespace element after each series of 2 terms.
What should I do to get this resulting array?

```
['1', '3', ' ', '5', '4', ' ', '8', '2']
```

Thank you!

Comment: There must be several methods to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.insert()`, with a `slice` to specify the positions:

```
np.insert(x, slice(2, None, 2), ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
[ e for y in [ ["_", v] if i%2==0 and i!=0 else [v] for i,v in enumerate(x)] for e in y ]
```

Answer (score 0):

a naive solution:

```
x = np.array(['1', '3', '5', '4', '8', '2'])
new_x = np.array([])
for i in range(x.size):
    if (i %3 == 2):
        new_x = np.append(new_x, ' ')
    new_x = np.append(new_x, x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['1', '3', '5', '4', '8', '2'])
for i in range(2, len(x), 3):
    x = np.insert(x, i, ' ')
print(x)
# ['1' '3' ' ' '5' '4' ' ' '8' '2']
```